# Во́рохи или вороха́?

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, орфоэпия, существительные

Вопрос обозначился еще восьмого марта (после просмотра ["Служебного романа"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKB1BCr7cC4)).

*Что ты, осень, наделала с нами!

В красном золоте стынет земля.

**Пламя скорби свистит под ногами,**

**Вороха́ми** листвы шевеля.*
Н. Заболоцкий. Осеннее утро [1955]

Вспомнилось стихотворение Р. Рождественского ("Я богат..." [1967-1970]):

```
Я подамся  
от бумажных  
    запутанных во́рохов  
в государство  
переулков,  
    проспектов  
        и двориков.
```

Время написания практически одно и то же, но ударения — разные.
А как правильно, грамотно ***сегодня*** — **во́рохи** или **вороха́**?

И попутно. Почему же *пламя — **свистит**?*

Answer (score 2):

Большой толковый словарь русского языка (гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов). Взято с [Грамоты](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85&all=x).

> **ВОРОХ**, -а; **мн.** вóрохи, -ов; *(разг.)* ворохá, -ов; **м.**

С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова тоже пишут два варианта.

А вот [Викисловарь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85) и [Толковый словарь Ушакова](https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85) дают только **ворохá**.

Ударение в стихотворениях и песнях часто варьирует в угоду ритму (тем более если слово позволяет такие вольности).
Что же касается *"свиста"* пламени, так это, мне кажется, имеет не только художественный образ, но и прямой смысл, ведь пламя на самом деле может издавать свист.

Comment: Ну-у, думаю, что на словарь Ушакова тут ориентироваться нельзя — ведь 80 лет прошло. В этом словаре и слово _**чорт**_ есть (1938 г.).

Comment: Да, конечно. По этой ссылке есть много словарей, где Лопатин, Ожегов, Зализняк дают оба варианта без помет "разг." или "устар.".

Comment: А про "пламя" не совсем понятно - Вы имели в виду, почему автор использует прямое значение "свистит" для метафоричного "пламени скорби"?